# How do I Reply a Comment So it can capture the comment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Please Guys, I have a forum and I want users to be able to reply comments so that the reply would appear with the comment.

This is what I have:

```
public ActionResult Quote(int? id)
       {
           var user = User.Identity.Name;
           var userId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
           //var userId = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == user).UserId;
           if (User.Identity.Name == null)
           {
               return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
           }
           if (id == null)
           {
               return RedirectToAction("topics", "forum");
           }

           //var p = db.Posts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PostId == id.Value);
           var post = db.Posts.Find(id.Value);

           var comment = db.UserComments.FirstOrDefault();
           var usercomment = db.UserComments.Find(comment.UserCommentId);

           if (usercomment == null)
           {
               return RedirectToAction("topics");
           }

           return View(new Quote { UserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, PostId = id.Value, UserCommentId = usercomment.UserCommentId });
       }


   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult Quote(Quote quote, int id = 0)
   {

       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
           {
               System.Random randomInteger = new System.Random();
               int genNumber = randomInteger.Next(1000000);
               HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
               if (file.ContentLength > 0 && file.ContentType.ToUpper().Contains("JPEG") || file.ContentType.ToUpper().Contains("PNG") || file.ContentType.ToUpper().Contains("JPG"))
               {
                   WebImage img = new WebImage(file.InputStream);
                   if (img.Width > 500)
                   {
                       img.Resize(width: 500, height: 400, preserveAspectRatio: true, preventEnlarge: true);
                   }

                   if (img.Height > 700)
                   {
                       img.Resize(width: 500, height: 400, preserveAspectRatio: true, preventEnlarge: true);
                   }
                   string fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), Path.GetFileName(genNumber + file.FileName));
                   img.Save(fileName);
                   if (fileName == null)
                   {
                       ViewBag.image = "True";
                   }
                   quote.QuoteFile = fileName;
               }
           }
           var user = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
           //var userId = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserId == user);
           db.Quotes.Add(quote);
           quote.QuotedBy = User.Identity.Name;
           var post = db.Quotes.Include(f => f.Posts).Where(x=>x.UserCommentId == quote.UserCommentId).OrderByDescending(s => s.QuoteId);

           quote.DateQuoted = DateTime.Now;
           db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("topics", "forum", new { id = quote.PostId});
       }

       return View(quote);
   }

   public ActionResult _Quote(int id = 0)
   {
       //var comment = db.UserComments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PostId == id);
       var user = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
       var comments = db.Quotes.Where(x => x.PostId == id).ToList();
       //var quotes = db.UserComments.Where(x => x.PostId == id).ToList();

       var p = new UserComment();
       p.DateUserCommented = DateTime.Now;
       DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(p.DateUserCommented);
       string strDate = dt.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy - hh:mm tt");
       ViewBag.p = strDate;

       ViewBag.data = comments;

       return PartialView(comments);
   }
```

Comment: Please post the specific code which is relevant to your problem and explain which part is not specifically working / erroring out.

Comment: thats the reply controller

Comment: A user can reply a comment, but its not capturing the comment the user replied, rather its capturing another comment